# migrating data from mysql to postgres pgloade IRONCLAD::SIMPLE-OCTET-VECTOR

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am migrating data from MySQL to Postgres using pgloader.
My script works fine on my local machine. But as I am running pgloader to prod database it's giving me following error

`The value of SEQUENCE is "?;JAExN[^F#yZ:O_o3Mj...", which is not of type IRONCLAD::SIMPLE-OCTET-VECTOR.`

I have tried the following way but
https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/782.

I am not sure what went wrong. 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: What data type exactly is that? Can you please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete `CREATE TABLE` statement for the target table in question?

Comment: it's just standard error prior to migrate, Connection is not establish